# Dynamically change style on page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, inline-styles

As The page scrolls I want to change the spacing of lettering in H1.

I thought my codepen would work but obviously not, I'm also not sure if and how it's possible to also make the style different for each H1

Ideally I'd like this, so the nearer the top of the page the less spacing each H1 has:

```
<h1 style="letter-spacing:3px">this is the Title</h1>
<h1 style="letter-spacing:7px">this is the Title</h1>
<h1 style="letter-spacing:11px">this is the Title</h1>
<h1 style="letter-spacing:13px">this is the Title</h1>
```

https://codepen.io/steven-david-reid/pen/vYXWNYK

```js
var $output = $("h1");

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $("h1").offset().top,
    distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
  $('$output').css({
    'letter-spacing': distance
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<h1>this is the Title</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Change to `$output.css({` instead of `$('$output').css({`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CodePen works, just a slight mistake in your JS.  Instead of `$('$output').css({'letter-spacing': distance})`, it should be `$output.css({'letter-spacing': distance})`

**EDIT:**
The goal is to have large letter spacings that converge to zero the closer the text gets to the top of the page as we scroll.  Note the `Math.max($(this).offset().top - scrollTop, 0)` which is used to ensure that the letter-spacing doesn't turn negative.  Then it is divided by 20; that's an arbitrary number, it's just to scale back the letter spacing as the distance is very large.

```
var $output = $("h1");

function changeLetterSpacing() {
    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $("h1").offset().top;
    $output.css('letter-spacing', function(d) { 
        return Math.max($(this).offset().top - scrollTop, 0)/20 + "px"; 
    })
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    changeLetterSpacing();
});
changeLetterSpacing();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make the change for each individual H1 and not apply the first one to all?

Comment: @Tomate sure, can you update your question with an example of how the H1s should look like at one scroll?

Comment: As requested, hope it make sense, I think that I need to make each h1 a $this instance (sorry if my language is incorrect - it's been a long time since I did scripting like this)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you meant, but if you mean that you want the h1 size to change when the page is scrolled from the top, then you can do this...

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $("#yourH1");
    $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

and add the scrolled class to the css
example:

```
.scrolled {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

again, very sorry if I have not understood you correctly, I'm new here